# Disable items of view pager adapter

Tags: android

I have two views in a view pager item,whenever first view is visible,i wan't to disable click on second view,but second view should be still visible.Any help will please.

Comment: Most probably ,you have set click inside viewpager's adapter item.
Post your code snippet for more insights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a condition in your pager adapter class if first view is visible then add 
setEnable(false) for second view it'll be visible but not clickable.

Comment: I have used all these condition.  myviewpager.setFocusable(false);
            myviewpager.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            myviewpager.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
            myviewpager.setLongClickable(false);
            myviewpager.setClickable(false);
            myviewpager.setPressed(false);
            myviewpager.setSelected(false);
            myviewpager.setEnabled(false);